# Error Namespace 'sec' is not bound al implementar Security Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, spring-security

estoy intentando implementar thymeleaf con spring security pero estoy teniendo el siguiente problema.

Al implementar la propiedad sec:authorize me aparece el siguiente mensaje: `Namespace 'sec' is not bound`. Cuando previamente lo tengo implementado ya en la parte del head. Si le digo que me lo implemente, lo hace, pero me dice que no lo encuentra y me sale el mismo error de nuevo: `Namespace 'sec' is not bound`.

```
<head
        th:replace="fragments/head" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></head>
<body>
<header th:replace="fragments/header"></header>
<main style="padding-left: 140px; padding-right: 140px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom: 60px">

    <h3>Registrar usuario</h3>

    <div th:if="${registerUserSuccesfull}" class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <p th:text="${registerUserSuccesfull}" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></p>
    </div>

    <form th:action="@{/new-user}" method="post" th:object="${user}">

        <label type="text" style="padding-top: 10px;">Usuario*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{username}" required>

        <label type="text" style="padding-top: 10px;">Contraseña*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="inputPassword" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{password}"
               required>

        <label type="text" style="padding-top: 10px;">E-mail*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputEmail" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{email}" required>

        <div class="row g-3" style="padding-top: 10px;">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label type="text">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{name}">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label type="text">Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{surname}">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" >
                <label type="text">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" th:field="*{birthDate}">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" sec:authorize="" >
                <label type="text">Role</label>
                <select type="for" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="role">
                    <option th:value="USER">User</option>
                    <option th:value="ADMIN">Admin</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="text-start" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Registrar cuenta</button>
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" onclick="history.back()">Volver</a>
        </div>
    </form>

</main>
<footer th:replace="fragments/footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pantallazo del error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo por aqui mi archivo **pom.xml** por si hubiera algún error en las dependencias. Estoy implementando la dependencia sobre thymeleaf security como se puede ver.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AplicacionWebFILMOTOKIO</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AplicacionWebFILMOTOKIO</name>
    <description>AplicacionWebFILMOTOKIO</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>3.6.3</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>3.6.3</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```